# CreateMsgQueue fails with Win32Error -2147467259

Tags: vb.net, winapi, compact-framework, windows-ce, compact-framework2.0

I've recreated some of the [OpenNetCF](https://www.opennetcf.com/) components like [PowerManagement](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/d3976aad-f969-c1e4-0dc4-dc146d338857.htm) and [DeviceStatusMonitor](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/83136fa5-0376-da13-48e1-71e75802e843.htm). But since they never raised any events I suspected that something was wrong. My first thought was to check the [P2PMessageQueue](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/e69d4a80-d286-d030-b7bc-07d0e3a979ab.htm) which they both depends on. And then BAM, the [CreateMsgQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885180.aspx) returns *IntPtr.Zero*. Checking for the last Win32Error gives me an error code of value -2147467259 (minus).

Is this just another generic error code that doesn't provide any hints?

Any help would be appreciated.

(FYI: WinCE 5.0, CF 2.0)

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try

            Dim lpName As String = "MyQueue"
            Dim lpOptions As MSGQUEUEOPTIONS = New MSGQUEUEOPTIONS()
            Dim hMsgQ As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

            lpOptions.bReadAccess = True
            lpOptions.dwMaxMessages = 0
            lpOptions.cbMaxMessage = &H1000
            lpOptions.dwFlags = MSGQUEUE_ALLOW_BROKEN
            lpOptions.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(lpOptions)

            hMsgQ = CreateMsgQueue(lpName, lpOptions)

            If (hMsgQ = IntPtr.Zero) Then
                Throw New Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
            Else
                CloseMsgQueue(hMsgQ)
            End If

        Catch ex As Win32Exception
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format(String.Format("Win32Exception: {0}", ex.ErrorCode)))
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    <DllImport("coredll.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function CloseMsgQueue(ByVal hMsgQ As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("coredll.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function CreateMsgQueue(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpOptions As MSGQUEUEOPTIONS) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure MSGQUEUEOPTIONS
        Public dwSize As Integer
        Public dwFlags As Integer
        Public dwMaxMessages As Integer
        Public cbMaxMessage As Integer
        Public bReadAccess As Boolean
    End Structure

    Private Const MSGQUEUE_ALLOW_BROKEN As Integer = 2
    Private Const MSGQUEUE_NOPRECOMMIT As Integer = 1
    Private Const MSGQUEUE_MSGALERT As Integer = 1

End Class
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you recreating them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lpOptions` parameter is declared incorrectly. You declare it as `ByVal` but it should be `ByRef`.

That said, `-2147467259` is a bit of an oddity. That's not a Win32 error code. That's a COM `HRESULT`. Specifically it's `0x80004005`. Which is the COM wrapper around the Win32 `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Not sure where you get a COM `HRESULT` from in this code mind you, but it would appear that you don't have sufficient rights for what you are attempting.

Comment: You're absolutely right, many thanks! Changing from *ByVal* to *ByRef* fixed the problem. In the OpenNetCF the MSGQUEUEOPTIONS is a class not a structure as I've done.

Comment: Declaring it as a class is also a good way to go. It allows you to pass `null`. Personally that's how I tend to translate C++ structs for my p/invokes.